# MS ReportViewer TableAdapter not working

Tags: dataset, rdlc, reportviewer2008

I am having trouble creating a DataSet for an MS ReportViewer Local Report.

The problem I am seeing where I have a Stored Procedure that is executes a dynamic SQL String. The DataSet can see the parameters but is as the results are passed through strings it of course can see the fields.

Is there away of getting the dataset to see this stored procedure and be able to bind to a report?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server did not have the necessary MS ReportViewer DLLs